# Choose function to apply based on the validity of an expression

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, overloading, template-meta-programming

The problem is the following, in `C++14`:

- Let's have two functions `FV&& valid_f`, `FI&& invalid_f`, and arguments `Args&&... args`
- The function `apply_on_validity` should apply `valid_f` on `args` if the expression `std::forward<FV>(valid_f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` is valid
- Otherwise and if `std::forward<FV>(invalid_f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` is a valid expression, `apply_on_validity` should apply `invalid_f` on `args`
- Otherwise `apply_on_validity` should do nothing

I guess the code should look like something like this:

```
template <class FV, class FI, class... Args, /* Some template metaprog here */>
void apply_on_validity(FV&& valid_f, FI&& invalid_f, Args&&... args)
{
    // Apply valid_f by default
    std::forward<FV>(valid_f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <class FV, class FI, class... Args, /* Some template metaprog here */>
void apply_on_validity(FV&& valid_f, FI&& invalid_f, Args&&... args)
{
    // Apply invalid_f if valid_f does not work
    std::forward<FV>(invalid_f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <class FV, class FI, class... Args, /* Some template metaprog here */>
void apply_on_validity(FV&& valid_f, FI&& invalid_f, Args&&... args)
{
    // Do nothing when neither valid_f nor invalid_f work
}
```

But I don't really know how to do that. Any idea?

---

Link to the generalization [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031216/apply-the-first-valid-function-of-a-set-of-n-functions).

Comment: You may consider looking at [`void_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) and having SFINAE based in a `void_t` expression.

Comment: but do you want this when `valid_f` and `invalid_f` are arguments of `apply_on_validity()`? Not with two know and fixed functions?

Comment: Cannot *wait* for `if constexpr`...

Comment: @Barry Same here :)

Comment: @Barry what do you mean, *wait*? It's already in clang 3.9 from apt.llvm.org and in gcc SVN tip of trunk (Ubuntu 17.04 testing distro has .deb packages)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take:

```
template <int N> struct rank : rank<N-1> {};
template <> struct rank<0> {};
```

and then:

```
template <class FV, class FI, class... Args>
auto apply_on_validity_impl(rank<2>, FV&& valid_f, FI&& invalid_f, Args&&... args)
    -> decltype(std::forward<FV>(valid_f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...), void())
{
    std::forward<FV>(valid_f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <class FV, class FI, class... Args>
auto apply_on_validity_impl(rank<1>, FV&& valid_f, FI&& invalid_f, Args&&... args)
    -> decltype(std::forward<FI>(invalid_f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...), void())
{
    std::forward<FI>(invalid_f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <class FV, class FI, class... Args>
void apply_on_validity_impl(rank<0>, FV&& valid_f, FI&& invalid_f, Args&&... args)
{

}

template <class FV, class FI, class... Args>
void apply_on_validity(FV&& valid_f, FI&& invalid_f, Args&&... args)
{
    return apply_on_validity_impl(rank<2>{}, std::forward<FV>(valid_f), std::forward<FI>(invalid_f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3f78fc21f0b6311)

Comment: a little explanation: the `decltype` uses SFINAE to ensure that the template function is enabled for the specified expression. The `rank` parameter is there to disambiguate and prioritize the overloads in case that more than one template function overload is valid.

Comment: Well, I just finished my solution, and discovered you had posted exactly what I came up with.

Answer (score 11):

[Piotr Skotnicki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42030223/27678) is superb, but code like that makes me feel compelled to point out how much cleaner C++17 will be thanks to `constexpr if` and additional type traits like `is_callable`: <strike>[Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/KewzOMUPa7x5mibF)</strike> [Demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/YLtdJ3LPysgBYv9y)<sup>*This version creates more warnings but is simpler</sup>

```
template <class FV, class FI, class... Args>
void apply_on_validity(FV&& valid_f, FI&& invalid_f, Args&&... args)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_callable_v<FV(Args...)>)
        std::cout << "Apply valid_f by default\n";
    else
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_callable_v<FI(Args...)>)
            std::cout << "Apply invalid_f if valid_f does not work\n";
        else
            std::cout << "Do nothing when neither valid_f nor invalid_f work\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: _You could replace those complicated `is_callable_v` checks with something like `is_callable_v<FV(Args...)>`, for most scenarios._ When is this not the case? I believe these are exactly equivalent in this context (i.e. when used on types deduced from forwarding references).

Comment: @Barry and yuri kilochek:  I was initially thinking of ref-qualified functors when I wrote that, but it seems that `is_callable` has it covered. Now gcc likes to give me lots of warnings, but it works

Answer (score 7):

Here's an alternative answer, just for kicks. We need a `static_if`:

```
template <class T, class F> T&& static_if(std::true_type, T&& t, F&& ) { return std::forward<T>(t); }
template <class T, class F> F&& static_if(std::false_type, T&& , F&& f) { return std::forward<F>(f); }
```

And an `is_callable`. Since you're just supporting functions, we can do it as:

```
template <class Sig, class = void>
struct is_callable : std::false_type { };

template <class F, class... Args>
struct is_callable<F(Args...), void_t<decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...))>>
: std::true_type
{ };
```

And then we can construct the logic in place:

```
template <class FV, class FI, class... Args>
void apply_on_validity(FV&& valid_f, FI&& invalid_f, Args&&... args)
{
    auto noop = [](auto&&...) {};

    static_if(
        is_callable<FV&&(Args&&...)>{},
        std::forward<FV>(valid_f),
        static_if(
            std::is_callable<FI&&(Args&&...)>{},
            std::forward<FI>(invalid_f),
            noop
        )
    )(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: @Is this method generalizable here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031216/apply-the-first-valid-function-of-a-set-of-n-functions?

Answer (score 3):

First, a homebrew version of C++2a's `is_detected`:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

namespace details {
  template<class...>using void_t=void;
  template<template<class...>class Z, class=void, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:std::true_type{};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply = typename details::can_apply<Z, void, Ts...>::type;
```

As it happens, std::result_of_t is the trait we want to test.

```
template<class Sig>
using can_call = can_apply< std::result_of_t, Sig >;
```

now can_call< Some(Sig,Goes,Here) > is true_type iff the expression you want can be called.

Now we write some compile-time if dispatch machinery.

```
template<std::size_t I>
using index_t=std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;
template<std::size_t I>
constexpr index_t<I> index_v{};

constexpr inline index_t<0> dispatch_index() { return {}; }
template<class B0, class...Bs,
  std::enable_if_t<B0::value, int> =0
>
constexpr index_t<0> dispatch_index( B0, Bs... ) { return {}; }
template<class B0, class...Bs,
  std::enable_if_t<!B0::value, int> =0
>
constexpr auto dispatch_index( B0, Bs... ) { 
  return index_v< 1 + dispatch_index( Bs{}...) >;
}

template<class...Bs>
auto dispatch( Bs... ) {
  using I = decltype(dispatch_index( Bs{}... ));
  return [](auto&&...args){
    return std::get<I::value>( std::make_tuple(decltype(args)(args)..., [](auto&&...){}) );
  };
}
```

dispatch( SomeBools... ) returns a lambda. The first of the SomeBools which is compile-time truthy (has a ::value that evaluates to true in a boolean context) determines what the returned lambda does. Call that the dispatch index.

It returns the dispatch_index'd argument to the next call, and an empty lambda if that is one-past-the-end of the list.

```
template <class FV, class FI, class... Args /*, Some template metaprog here */>
void apply_on_validity(FV&& valid_f, FI&& invalid_f, Args&&... args)
{
  dispatch(
    can_call<FV(Args...)>{},
    can_call<FI(Args...)>{}
  )(
    [&](auto&& valid_f, auto&&)->decltype(auto) {
      return decltype(valid_f)(valid_f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    },
    [&](auto&&, auto&& invalid_f)->decltype(auto) {
      return decltype(invalid_f)(valid_f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
  )(
    valid_f, invalid_f
  );
}
```

and done, [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f05280209575fa8).

We could make this generic to enable nary version. First index_over:

```
template<class=void,  std::size_t...Is >
auto index_over( std::index_sequence<Is...> ){
  return [](auto&&f)->decltype(auto){
    return decltype(f)(f)( std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{}... );
  };
}
template<std::size_t N>
auto index_over(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N> ={}){
  return index_over(std::make_index_sequence<N>{} );
}
```

Then auto_dispatch:

```
template<class...Fs>
auto auto_dispatch( Fs&&... fs ) {
  auto indexer =  index_over<sizeof...(fs)>();
  auto helper = [&](auto I)->decltype(auto){ 
    return std::get<decltype(I)::value>( std::forward_as_tuple( decltype(fs)(fs)... ) );
  };
  return indexer
  (
    [helper](auto...Is){
      auto fs_tuple = std::forward_as_tuple( helper(Is)... );
      return [fs_tuple](auto&&...args) {
        auto dispatcher = dispatch(can_call<Fs(decltype(args)...)>{}...);
        auto&& f0 = dispatcher(std::get<decltype(Is)::value>(fs_tuple)...);
        std::forward<decltype(f0)>(f0)(decltype(args)(args)...);
      };
    }
  );
}
```

with test code:

```
auto a = [](int x){ std::cout << x << "\n"; };
auto b = [](std::string y){ std::cout << y << "\n";  };
struct Foo {};
auto c = [](Foo){ std::cout << "Foo\n";  };
int main() {
  auto_dispatch(a, c)( 7 );
  auto_dispatch(a, c)( Foo{} );
  auto_dispatch(a, b, c)( Foo{} );
  auto_dispatch(a, b, c)( "hello world" );
}
```

[Live example](http://rextester.com/PZSZ46339)