# Apply the first valid function of a set of N functions

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, overloading, template-meta-programming

This previous answer shows how to apply function based on the validity of a call: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42030223/882932). However, it applies to two functions. I was wondering if the concept could be generalized to `N` functions using smart template programming tricks, in C++14.

The problem is the following:

```
template <std::size_t N, class... X>
/* [Return type] */ apply_on_validity(X&&... x)
{
    // Tricks here
}

// The function would be equivalent to a hypothetical
// template <std::size_t N, class... F, class... Args>
// [Return type] apply_on_validity(F&&... f, Args&&... args)
// where N = sizeof...(F) is the number of functions
```

On the execution side:

```
apply_on_validity<3>(f1, f2, f3, a, b, c, d, e);
```

Would:

- call `f1(a, b, c, d, e)` if the expression is valid, otherwise
- call `f2(a, b, c, d, e)` if the expression is valid, otherwise
- call `f3(a, b, c, d, e)` if the expression is valid, otherwise
- do nothing

And in all cases, it would return the result of the function that was executed.

On the calling side, the template parameter `3` indicates the number of functions that have been specified.

Is it doable in C++14, and if so, how?

Comment: I would suggest instead building a callable object that that has the desired semantics as a more convenient interface: `make_first_valid_callable(f1, f2, f3)(a, b, c, d, e);`, which does not force users to manually keep track of function count and is more composable.

Comment: @yurikilochek That's smart. Love it! Now the question is how to solve the problem using that syntax...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another fun one for kicks, abusing overload resolution. We're going to transform each function into another function that takes a `rank` argument, combine all of our functions together, and then just invoke them. The selection will just fall out naturally from the overload set.

Our ranker is just this ladder of types:

```
template <int I> struct rank : rank<I-1> { };
template <> struct rank<0> { };
```

We need a function transformer:

```
template <class T, class F>
auto prepend_arg(F&& f) {
    return [f=std::forward<F>(f)](T, auto&&... args)
        -> decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...))
    {
        return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
}
```

And then:

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is, std::size_t... Js,
    class... X>
decltype(auto) apply_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>,
                          std::index_sequence<Js...>,
                          X&&... x)
{
    auto all = std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<X>(x)...);

    return overload(
        // all of our function cases
        prepend_arg<rank<N-Is>>(std::get<Is>(all))...,
        // base case: do nothing
        [](rank<0>, auto&&...) {}
    )(rank<N>{}, std::get<N+Js>(all)...);
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//               pass in all the arguments    
}

template <std::size_t N, class... X>
decltype(auto) apply_on_validity(X&&... x) {
    return apply_impl<N>(
        std::make_index_sequence<N>{},
        std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(X)-N>{},
        std::forward<X>(x)...);
}
```

I leave `overload()` as an exercise.

Answer (score 8):

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Js, typename Args>
auto apply_on_validity_impl(int, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>, std::index_sequence<Js...>, Args&& args)
{
    // Nothing here
}

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t I, std::size_t... Js, typename Args>
auto apply_on_validity_impl(int, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>, std::index_sequence<Js...>, Args&& args)
    -> decltype(std::get<I>(std::forward<Args>(args))(std::get<Js + N>(std::forward<Args>(args))...))
{
    return std::get<I>(std::forward<Args>(args))(std::get<Js + N>(std::forward<Args>(args))...);
}

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t I, std::size_t... Js, typename Args>
decltype(auto) apply_on_validity_impl(char, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>, std::index_sequence<Js...> seq, Args&& args)
{
    return apply_on_validity_impl<N>(0, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I + 1>{}, seq, std::forward<Args>(args));
}

template <std::size_t N, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) apply_on_validity(Args&&... args)
{
    return apply_on_validity_impl<N>(0, std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>{}, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args) - N>{}, std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5Al45AQLFA87e9Xv)

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t I, std::size_t... Js, typename Args>
decltype(auto) apply_on_validity_impl(std::index_sequence<Js...> seq, Args&& args)
{        
    if constexpr (I == N)
    {
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<std::tuple_element_t<I, Args>, std::tuple_element_t<Js + N, Args>...>)
    {
        return std::get<I>(std::forward<Args>(args))(std::get<Js + N>(std::forward<Args>(args))...);
    }
    else
    {
        return apply_on_validity_impl<N, I + 1>(seq, std::forward<Args>(args));
    }
}

template <std::size_t N, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) apply_on_validity(Args&&... args)
{
    return apply_on_validity_impl<N, 0>(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args) - N>{}, std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pe7X6ZsmIvsgZG8i)

Comment: `std::remove_reference_t` is redundant.

Comment: Pass this 1000 lambdas and it will break.  ;)  (recursive template instantiation limit)

Answer (score 5):

The syntax you are using is kind of awkward, since you have to know exactly how many functions you have. Combined with [Piotr Skotnicki's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42031538/1896169), this solves that problem:

```
// Would be a local class except for the fact that it needs
// to have templates, thus can't be local to the function.
template<class... Fs>
class apply_first_f final {
public:
    apply_first_f(Fs&&... fs)
        : fs_{ std::forward<Fs>(fs)... }
    {}

    template<class... Args>
    decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... args) const
    {
        return apply_impl<sizeof...(Args)>(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Fs)>{}, std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }
private:
    std::tuple<std::decay_t<Fs>...> fs_;

    template<size_t argsSize, size_t... Is, class Args>
    decltype(auto) apply_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Args&& args) const
    {
        return apply_on_validity_impl<sizeof...(Fs)>(
            0,
            std::integral_constant<size_t, 0>{},
            std::make_index_sequence<argsSize>{},
            std::tuple_cat(
                std::forward_as_tuple(std::get<Is>(fs_)...),
                std::forward<Args>(args)
            )
        );
    }
};

template<class... Fs>
auto make_apply_first_valid_f(Fs&&... fs)
{
    return apply_first_f<Fs...>{ std::forward<Fs>(fs)... };
}
```

And the function can be used like so:

```
make_apply_first_valid_f(f1, f2, f3)(args);
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98e1a87f4ad4cb00) (adapted from Piotr's demo)

Using it with Piotr's C++ 1z example requires just a small change:

```
template<class... Fs>
class apply_first_f final {
    // ...
    template<size_t argsSize, size_t... Is, class Args>
    decltype(auto) apply_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Args&& args) const
    {
        return apply_on_validity_impl<sizeof...(Fs), /* added */ 0>(
            /* 0, */
            /* std::integral_constant<size_t, 0>{}, */
            std::make_index_sequence<argsSize>{},
            std::tuple_cat(
                std::forward_as_tuple(std::get<Is>(fs_)...),
                std::forward<Args>(args)
            )
        );
    }
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Might want to do `std::tuple<std::decay_t<Fs>...> fs_;` instead, so that the object can be safely stored.

Comment: @yurikilochek The only thing I wonder about that is if it requires more of the functions passed in.

Comment: It requires copy/move constructability, naturally. But this is hardly a problem as all `std` algorithms that use callbacks, `std::bind`, `std::function`, `std::thread`, etc require the same.

Comment: You probably shouldn't make callable types `final`, as that will play havoc with naive implementations of utilities like `overload` with which you may want to compose them (bad example but the only one I can think of offhand; some utilities may wish to derive from the type as a matter of composition, and there's no good reason to disallow it).

Answer (score 2):

I had answered this in the previous iteration, but the nary version had a bug, and clang had an internal compiler error which made it hard to find the bug.

I have since fixed the bug.  So here is a pile of metaprogramming, followed by solving your problem.

First, a homebrew version of C++2a's `is_detected`:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

namespace details {
  template<class...>using void_t=void;
  template<template<class...>class Z, class=void, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:std::true_type{};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply = typename details::can_apply<Z, void, Ts...>::type;
```

As it happens, std::result_of_t is the trait we want to test.

```
template<class Sig>
using can_call = can_apply< std::result_of_t, Sig >;
```

now can_call< Some(Sig,Goes,Here) > is true_type iff the expression you want can be called.

Now we write some compile-time if dispatch machinery.

```
template<std::size_t I>
using index_t=std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;
template<std::size_t I>
constexpr index_t<I> index_v{};

constexpr inline index_t<0> dispatch_index() { return {}; }
template<class B0, class...Bs,
  std::enable_if_t<B0::value, int> =0
>
constexpr index_t<0> dispatch_index( B0, Bs... ) { return {}; }
template<class B0, class...Bs,
  std::enable_if_t<!B0::value, int> =0
>
constexpr auto dispatch_index( B0, Bs... ) { 
  return index_v< 1 + dispatch_index( Bs{}...) >;
}

template<class...Bs>
auto dispatch( Bs... ) {
  using I = decltype(dispatch_index( Bs{}... ));
  return [](auto&&...args){
    return std::get<I::value>( std::make_tuple(decltype(args)(args)..., [](auto&&...){}) );
  };
}
```

dispatch( SomeBools... ) returns a lambda. The first of the SomeBools which is compile-time truthy (has a ::value that evaluates to true in a boolean context) determines what the returned lambda does. Call that the dispatch index.

It returns the dispatch_index'd argument to the next call, and an empty lambda if that is one-past-the-end of the list.

Now we want to be able to dispatch on a set of possibilities.  To make this simple (heh), we'll use `index_over`:

```
template<class=void,  std::size_t...Is >
auto index_over( std::index_sequence<Is...> ){
  return [](auto&&f)->decltype(auto){
    return decltype(f)(f)( std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{}... );
  };
}
template<std::size_t N>
auto index_over(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N> ={}){
  return index_over(std::make_index_sequence<N>{} );
}
```

which lets us expand parameter packs without having to build new functions.

Then we can write `auto_dispatch` as a single function template:

```
template<class...Fs>
auto auto_dispatch( Fs&&... fs ) {
  auto indexer =  index_over<sizeof...(fs)>();
  // some compilers dislike lambdas with unexpanded parameter packs.
  // this helps with that:
  auto helper = [&](auto I)->decltype(auto){ 
    return std::get<decltype(I)::value>( std::forward_as_tuple( decltype(fs)(fs)... ) );
  };
  // Get 0 through N-1 as compile-time constants:
  return indexer
  (
    [helper](auto...Is){
      // make tuple of functions:
      auto fs_tuple = std::forward_as_tuple( helper(Is)... );
      // This is what is returned from the `auto_dispatch` function
      // it perfect forwards into the correct lambda passed to `auto_dispatch`
      // based on which is the first one which can be invoked by
      // args...
      return [fs_tuple](auto&&...args) {
        // dispatcher knows which one can be called
        auto dispatcher = dispatch(can_call<Fs(decltype(args)...)>{}...);
        // here we get the first one that can be called, or an empty lambda:
        auto&& f0 = dispatcher(std::get<decltype(Is)::value>(fs_tuple)...);
        // here we do the actual call:
        std::forward<decltype(f0)>(f0)(decltype(args)(args)...);
      };
    }
  );
}
```

with test code:

```
auto a = [](int x){ std::cout << x << "\n"; };
auto b = [](std::string y){ std::cout << y << "\n";  };
struct Foo {};
auto c = [](Foo){ std::cout << "Foo\n";  };
int main() {
  auto_dispatch(a, c)( 7 );
  auto_dispatch(a, c)( Foo{} );
  auto_dispatch(a, b, c)( Foo{} );
  auto_dispatch(a, b, c)( "hello world" );
}
```

[Live example](http://rextester.com/PZSZ46339)

The only N-ary recursive template instantiation above is `dispatch_index`.  I can make that log-depth with a bit of work (divide and conquer).  Getting it constant depth is hard.  I will think on it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`boost::hana::overload_linearly`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/group__group-functional.html#gaa46de6f618d9f14edb1589b36b6e75ec):

```
hana::overload_linearly(f1, f2, f3)(a, b, c, d, e)
```

If none of the expressions are valid, it's a compile error, but it's easy to make it do nothing in that case:

```
hana::overload_linearly(f1, f2, f3, [](auto&&...) {})(a, b, c, d, e)
```

---

Alternatively, use [`boost::hof::first_of`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/first_of.html), which does the same thing