# No matching function std::forward with lambdas

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++14, perfect-forwarding

Consider the following code, inspired from Barry's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42036525/882932) question:

```
// Include
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// Generic overload rank
template <std::size_t N> 
struct overload_rank 
: overload_rank<N - 1> 
{
};

// Default overload rank
template <> 
struct overload_rank<0> 
{
};

// Prepend argument to function
template <std::size_t N, class F>
auto prepend_overload_rank(F&& f) {
    using rank = overload_rank<N>;
    return [f = std::forward<F>(f)](rank, auto&&... args) -> decltype(auto) {
        return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); // here
    };
}

// Main
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto f = [](int i){return i;};
    prepend_overload_rank<5>(f)(overload_rank<5>(), 1);
    return 0;
}
```

It is not compiling because of line noted `here`, and I don't understand why:

```
With g++:
error: no matching function for call to 'forward<main(int, char**)::<lambda(int)>&>(const main(int, char**)::<lambda(int)>&)'
With clang:
error: no matching function for call to 'forward'
```

Replacing

```
return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
```

by

```
return f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
```

apparently makes it work, but again, I don't understand why, and my goal is to achieve a perfect forwarding of the function.

Comment: Hint: adding `mutable` fixes it (`return [f = std::forward<F>(f)](rank, auto&&... args) mutable -> decltype(auto) {`). `std::forward` is a red herring; this is simply an issue of const-correctness.

Comment: `decltype(auto)` is wrong. You need SFINAE to kick in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently compilers are either bugged or allowed to declare variables captured by copy as `const` when the `mutable` specifier is not present.
Ironically, the following compiles with GCC, but it doesn't with clang:

```
#include <type_traits>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i = 0;
    [j = i](){ static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(j), const int>::value, "!"); }();
}
```

To work around the issue in both cases you can do this:

```
return [f = std::forward<F>(f)](auto&&... args) -> decltype(auto) {
    return std::forward<decltype(f)>(f)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); // here
};
```

That is, you can omit the `mutable` keyword, but you have to use the actual type of the copy of `f` within the lambda. Note that the *original* `f` is a non-const reference to a lambda function, thus `F` can differ from the type `decltype(f)` within the lambda.
This is valid in any case, even for `mutable` lambda. As an example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include<utility>

struct S {};

template<typename T>
void f(T &&t) {
    [t = std::forward<T>(t)]()mutable{ static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(t), S>::value, "!"); }();
    // the following doesn't compile for T is S& that isn't the type of t within the lambda
    //[t = std::forward<T>(t)]()mutable{ static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(t), T>::value, "!"); }();
}

int main() {
    S s;
    f(s);
}
```

In general, you should use the actual type of the captured variable instead of the type given in a surrounding context.
In the specific case, even though the compiler wrongly declares the captured variable as `const`, you can make it work without the `mutable` specifier as long as the function operator of `f` is `const` (that is your case, for `f` is `main` isn't `mutable` as well).

Another way to let your snippet work is this (as suggested in the comments to the question):

```
return [f = std::forward<F>(f)](auto&&... args) mutable -> decltype(auto) {
    return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); // here
};
```

In this case, variables captured by copy cannot be forced to be `const` and the type is the expected one.
Anyway, I'd suggest to take the advice above even if you are planning to use the `mutable` specifier.

---

Note.
As discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42046021/non-mutable-lambda-function-are-copy-captured-variables-allowed-to-be-const) the problem arose because of a bug of GCC. The suggestion to use `decltype(f)` still stands. It addresses also other types of problems and works for the specific case. Moreover, in case the bug is fixed, the code will continue to work properly.

Comment: Perhaps GCC is bugged, but that bug has nothing to do with OP's problem.

Comment: @T.C. _GCC is bugged_ is only a part of the answer. I hope the rest can help. Any comment on that?