# Non mutable lambda function: are copy-captured variables allowed to be const?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, language-lawyer

While trying to reply to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044116/no-matching-function-stdforward-with-lambdas) here on SO, I found a difference in how GCC and clang work with lambdas.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    [j = i](){ static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(j), const int>::value, "!"); }();
}
```

In this case, clang [rejects the snippet](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/FvgXYNuXpRt4oSA9), while GCC [accepts the code](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/GBP6v7Y3IMTAj1ee).

On the other side, both of them accept the code below (for obvious reasons):

```
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    [j = i]()mutable{ static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(j), int>::value, "!"); }();
}
```

Are compilers allowed to declare variables captured by copy as const for non-mutable lambdas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mutable` doesn't matter here.

In [expr.prim.lambda]:

> An *init-capture* behaves as if it declares and explicitly captures a variable of the form “`auto` init-capture ;”

And from [dcl.type.simple]:

> For an expression `e`, the type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows: [...] if `e` is an unparenthesized *id-expression* or an unparenthesized class member access (5.2.5), `decltype(e)` is the type of the entity named by `e`.

So `decltype(j)` should be `int`. This is a gcc bug, reported as [79378](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79378).

Comment: Interesting. I'll open another bug to GCC. Thank you.

Comment: @skypjack Just did.